# Fixing a grammar

Tags: formal-grammars

I'm sorry I don't know the technical terminology for this. All I see in my notes is fixing a grammar. Can someone please help explain this? What exactly is this called?

[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Answer (score 0):

It is just [Left Recursion Removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_Frecursion#Removing_left_recursion). The algorithms removing recursion for direct and indirect case are presented on the wiki page.

The case in your notes are direct recursion, in general form. $A\to A\alpha|\beta$. It can be roughly explained as below:

Following the rule $A\to A\alpha|\beta$ several times, one can get 
$$A\to A\alpha\to A\alpha\alpha\to\dotsb\to A\alpha\alpha\dotsm\alpha\to\beta\alpha\alpha\dotsm\alpha$$
ie. $A\to\beta\alpha^k, k\ge 0$. rewrite the rule as $A\to\beta A'$, then the rest $A'\to\alpha^k$ has a non-left recursive form: $A'\to\alpha A'|\epsilon$. In together, we get $$\begin{align}A\to&\beta A'\\A'\to&\alpha A'|\epsilon\end{align}$$ which is a rewrite of $A\to A\alpha|\beta$ while removing left recursion.

Your example $X\to XYaBb|XZ|ba|Bw$ is equivalent to $X\to X(YaBb|Z)|(ba|Bw)$, here $\alpha=YaBb|Z$ and $\beta=ba|Bw$.